# In my react shouldComponentUpdate function，this.props and nextprops have all the same attributes, but they are not equal

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In my react shouldComponentUpdate function，this.props and nextprops have all the same attributes, but they are not equal.My code:

```
shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps) {
    console.log(this.props);
    console.log(nextProps);
    console.log('nextProps vs this.props:', nextProps === this.props);
    console.log('this.props.style vs nextProps.style:', this.props.style === nextProps.style);
    console.log('this.props.data vs nextProps.data',this.props.data === nextProps.data);
    return true;
  }
```

the output is :
[image]

My confusion is whether the props has some hidden attributes.

Comment: Have you ever try react PureComponent or react-addon-shallow-compare

Comment: I will hava a try.Thank you,@Muhaimin

Comment: the same question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48643486/react-native-checking-previous-state

Answer (score 0):

Object comparison doesn't work that way.

For example take the following code:

```
test_a = {key: 'value'}
test_b = {key: 'value'}
console.log(test_a == test_b) //false
```

There are many ways to properly compare js objects for equality by value, and someone in the comment section has already provided a link to a previous thread on the topic.

Comment: I know how to compare two object,but in the situation the focus is on the `react shouldComponentUpdate function` which is import to the render performance.If every attributes are equal, then the `this.props` and the `nextprops ` should be equal, then it will not rerender.

Comment: "If every attributes are equal, then the this.props and the nextprops should be equal,": That is not true.  Look at my answer again.  Comparing objects checks to see if they are occupying the same memory address, not whether their attributes are the same.

Comment: What you mean is correct, wheather two objects are equal is determined by the memory address. But in the situlation `react` shuold not generate new props when no prop attributes had changed,I don't know why.`https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate`

Answer (score -2):

Just do a `JSON.stringify(this.props) === JSON.stringify(nextProps)`

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#shouldcomponentupdate 
We do not recommend doing deep equality checks or using JSON.stringify() in shouldComponentUpdate(). It is very inefficient and will harm performance.