# react native checking previous state

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I cant check a value of a previous state in render

my code is

```
    this.setState(previousState => ({
  if(name!=previousState.name){

                 name:name,
                uri:uri,
                fbid:fbid,


 }           
        }));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a component lifecycle method,`componentWillUpdate` by which you can check the current and the new state. It is always called when the props or state changes. For example:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  console.log(nextState); //will show the new state
  console.log(this.state); //will show the previous state
}
```

For reference, visit: [componentWillUpdate](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentwillupdate)

Answer (score 2):

```
handelFilterVisibility = () => {
  this.setState(prevState => ({
    isFilterVisible: !prevState.isFilterVisible
  }));
}
```

Comment: Please add some explanation

Comment: handelFilterVisibility -> this is a custom method which will invoke when someone clicks a button  & prevState -> is the previous state, so in this method, we take the previous state and change 'isFilterVisible'

Comment: add explanation in answer, not in comment section.

Answer (score 0):

react-native do have a lifecycle method for this which contains your previous state as well as new state you can compare both of them into this LC method.
you can read about lifecycle methods over here
https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html

Comment: `componentWillReceiveProps` does not contain previous and new state. You can only access the current state.

Answer (score 0):

> handelFilterVisibility -> this is a custom method which will invoke
>   when someone clicks a button & prevState -> is the previous state, so
>   in this method, we take the previous state and change it's property
>   'isFilterVisible'

Answer (score 0):

I think we can answer this in a more detailed and recent way:

```
const MyVideoPlayer = () => {
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);

  return (
    <View>
      <!--...my video player...-->
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => setIsPlaying(prevState => !prevState)}>
        <!-- My setIsPlaying is returning me the previous state in "prevState"
         and me in turn returning it's negation. So every time the user klicks the
         button it will change from play to pause -->
        {isPlaying ? <PauseButton /> : <PlayButton />}
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};
```